# Generalized list printing function in SML

Tags: list, printing, sml

I have to write a function to print a list in SML with the following type signature :

```
     val printGenList = fn : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> unit
```

The "printGenList" will take two arguments function f and list l and applies the function f to each element of list l recursively.

Since I am new to ML, I am not able to implement it but I tried this code which is giving the different type signature

```
     fun printGenList = CONS(fib, fn => printGenList fib fibs);

 where,  fib is
        fun fib a b = CONS(a, fn => fib b (a+b));
 and fibs is
        val fibs = fib 0 1;
```

Comment: The type you give doesn't make much sense. Are you sure it is not supposed to be either `string` or `unit` in place of `'b`?

Comment: There is a very limited number of (quite useless) functions with the type `'a -> 'b`. The significant ones are: The function that never returns (`fun f x = f x`) and the function that throws an exception (`fun f x = raise Fail "Meh"`). It sounds unlikely that `f` should be one of these.

Comment: @SimonShine, note however that the function type appears in negative position (left of an arrow), so it rather is determined by how the function is _used_ by `printGenList`. In such a context, an arbitrary result type `'b` simply implies that the result is always ignored. Presumably, it is supposed to be the print function for list elements, so indeed the result wouldn't be used, and the caller of `printGenList` is free to pass a function of type `'a -> unit`. Still, I find that type rather misleading, especially for a homework question.

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is impossible, ML's type system doesn't support this type of polymorphism. If you Google, there are some printf libraries for SML that show you how to approach this -- for each type `t` that you want to print, you'll need to define a separate `t -> unit` function and compose them together.

EDIT: Oh, I see, you're not looking for a function to print lists of any type, you're looking for a higher order function that applies an `'a->'b` function to every element of a list... my mistake. This is what you need:

```
val rec printGenList = 
 fn (f : 'a -> 'b) =>
    (fn [] => ()
    | x::xs => (f(x); printGenList f xs))
```

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote? A "generalized list printing function" that works on data of all types isn't possible to implement in SML -- I tried to write one and had one of my professors explain why it was an exercise in futility to me.

Comment: "ML's type system doesn't support parametric polymorphism": I assume you meant "doesn't support _non_-parametric polymorphism".

Comment: Ah, you're right. I edited to be somewhat clearer, thank you.